# how to fix You should only render one navigator explicitly in your app in IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, reactjs, react-native

Im using "react-navigation" and react-native-router-flux in RN project
at android all is normal
But at IOS there is warning

> You should only render one navigator explicitly in your app, and other
>   navigators should be rendered by including them in that navigator.
>   Full details at:
>   https://reactnavigation.org/docs/common-mistakes.html#explicitly-rendering-more-than-one-navigator
>   - node_modules/expo/build/environment/logging.js:25:23 in warn
>   - node_modules/@react-navigation/native/src/createAppContainer.js:198:12
>   in componentDidMount$
>   - node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:44
>   in tryCatch
>   - node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:288:30
>   in invoke
>   - node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:44
>   in tryCatch
>   - node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:152:28
>   in invoke
>   - node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:187:17
>   in

This is my App.js

...

```
 return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RouterWithRedux>
          <Router>
            <Stack key="root" hideNavBar={true}>
              <Scene
                key="loginScreen"
                hideNavBar
                component={requireAuthNOT(LoginScreen)}
                title="Please Sign in"
              />
              <Scene
                key="ticketsListScreen"
                component={requireAuth(TicketsListScreen)}
                animation="fade"
                title="Home"
                hideNavBar={true}
              />
              <Scene
                key="ticketDetail"
                component={requireAuth(LoginDetail)}
                animation="fade"
                hideNavBar={true}
              />
            </Stack>
          </Router>
        </RouterWithRedux>
      </Provider>
    );
```

...

LoginScreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react"; 
import Logo from "../components/Auth/Logo";
import Form from "../components/Auth/Form";
import Wallpaper from "../components/Auth/Wallpaper";
import ButtonSubmit from "../components/Auth/ButtonSubmit";
import SignupSection from "../components/Auth/SignupSection";

export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Wallpaper>
        <Logo />
        <Form />
        <SignupSection />
        <ButtonSubmit />
      </Wallpaper>
    );
  }
}
```

TicketsListScreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Navigator from "./Navigator";

export default class ScreenTest extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Navigator />;
  }
}
```

Navigator.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TicketsListScreen from "./TicketsListScreen";
import VehicleScreen from "../VehicleScreen/VehicleScreen";
import SideBar from "../../components/Navigator/SideBar";
import SignOut from "../../screens/LogoutScreen";
import { createDrawerNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
const TicketScreenRouter = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: TicketsListScreen },
    Tickets: { screen: TicketsListScreen },
    "Vehicle Inspections": { screen: VehicleScreen },
    "Sign Out": { screen: SignOut }
  },
  {
    contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home"
  }
);
export default createAppContainer(TicketScreenRouter);
```

Im not sure what is issue.
I have read https://reactnavigation.org/docs/common-mistakes.html#explicitly-rendering-more-than-one-navigator

but that is not help for me

Thanks best regards

Comment: Don't use two navigators, You can use drawer from `router-flux` rather than `createDrawerNavigator` from `react-navigation`

Comment: I think there is one navigator

Comment: No, you are using two, one in App.js and other in Navigator.js

Comment: Thanks I try use drawer from router-flux. I have fixed that issue.

Comment: I am glad I helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is app.js

```
return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RouterWithRedux>
          <Scene key="root" hideNavBar={true}>
            <Scene
              key="loginScreen"
              hideNavBar
              component={requireAuthNOT(LoginScreen)}
              title="Please Sign in"
            />
            <Drawer
              open={false}
              type="overlay"
              key="drawer"
              contentComponent={SideBar}>
              <Scene
                key="VehicleInsections"
                component={requireAuth(VehicleScreen)}
                animation="fade"
                title="Vehicle"
                hideNavBar={true}
              />                 
          </Scene>
        </RouterWithRedux>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
```

Currently That is working as well for me 
Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/9799857/firu again.